# how can swipe card next and Previous in ZLSwipeableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7Exq.png)

for example first card green color second card white color third card yellow color . so first we swipe right .so now top view is white card after we swipe left so now top view is green card how can it possible

Comment: what is top view? what is card??  what have you tried???

Answer (score 0):

i think this is for you. As per your requirement this library will help you.

You can download source code from this link. SwipeView [GithubLink](https://github.com/nicklockwood/SwipeView)
Then use Paging Example.

[image]

Comment: nop buddy because i need all the view like in (i.e see ZLSwipeableView)stack z order

Comment: How can we speed up the swipe? Right now its very slow. Is there any property which speed up the swipe